# Definition Gutmensch

Tags: meaning, political-correctness

Bis vor ein paar Jahren kannte ich den Begriff "Gutmensch" nicht. Ich wurde damals aufgeklärt, dass in der Rechten Szene dieses Wort als Beschimpfung für deren Widersacher verwendet wird. Seit diesem Tag, verbinde ich deshalb das Wort "Gutmensch" mit Rechtsradikalen und deren Sprachgebrauch.
Eben habe ich einen Artikel der [ftd.de](http://www.ftd.de/lifestyle/outofoffice/%3aunternehmensberater-fuer-migranten-der-koefte-consultant/60066354.html?page=3) gelesen, in dem der Interviewer den Befragten als Gutmenschen bezeichnet. Nun bin ich doch sehr überrascht. Kann das Wort "Gutmensch" probemlos in einem rechtsradikalfreien Kontext verwendet werden?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Der Duden beschreibt die Bedeutung des Wortes wie folgt:

> [naiver] Mensch, der sich in einer als unkritisch, übertrieben, nervtötend o. ä. empfundenen Weise im Sinne der Political Correctness verhält, sich für die Political Correctness einsetzt

Kein Wunder also, dass Rechtsradikale das Wort für Widersacher verwenden. Wikipedia beschreibt daher auch, dass das Wort zumindest politisch vor allem im rechten und konservativem Bereich verwendet wird. Es beschreibt aber eigentlich generell eine übertriebene politische Korrektheit, oder auch "gut gemeint, aber nicht gut gemacht".

Außerdem werden einige private, liebevolle Gebräuche aufgezeigt, die sich keiner politischen Richtung zuordnen lassen. Dass bestimmte politische Richtungen das Wort häufig verwenden, heißt also nicht, dass es automatisch auch eine entsprechende Konnotation hat.

Im Grimm kommt das Wort nicht vor, ist also grundsätzlich jüngeren Ursprungs. NGrams zeigt eine massive Häufigkeitszunahme erst in den Neunzigern. Dadurch erklärt sich vielleicht auch, warum dir der Begriff erst seit einigen Jahren bekannt ist.

[image]

Comment: Danke, das erklärt mir (ebenfalls) sehr viel

Comment: Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Gutmensch%2CGutmenschen%2CGutmenschentum&year_start=1988&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3) und [Trends](https://google.de/trends/explore#q=Gutmensch%2C%20Gutmenschen%2C%20Gutmenschentum&geo=DE&date=1%2F2009%2085m) zum Selbernachgucken.

Answer (score 5):

Die [Gesellschaft für deutsche Sprache](http://www.gfds.de/sprachberatung/fragen-und-antworten/uebersichtsseite/gutmensch/) schreibt dazu:

> Unser Erstbeleg zu Gutmensch stammt aus dem Jahr 1985: In der US-amerikanischen Zeitschrift Forbes wurde Gutmensch auf den damaligen Gewerkschaftsführer Franz Steinkühler (IG Metall) bezogen.
>
> [...]
>
> Weithin bekannt wurde Gutmensch durch das sprachkritische Wörterbuch des Gutmenschen aus dem Jahr 1994, herausgegeben von Klaus Bittermann. Das Buch wandte sich gegen »Betroffenheitsjargon und Gesinnungskitsch«.
>
> [...]
>
> Mit dem Jahr 1994 setzen denn auch die von uns gesammelten Wortbelege reichlich ein. Im Sprachdienst-Beitrag »Wörter des Jahres 1997« wurde Gutmensch beschrieben und dabei als »Schmähwort«, als »Schlagwort zur Stigmatisierung des Protests, zur Diffamierung des moralischen Arguments« charakterisiert (Heft 2/1998, S. 53 f.).

Comment: +1, ich vermute, dass das thematische Umfeld der Gewerkschaften sogar die Wissensquelle desjenigen Bekannten war, von dem ich dieses Wort das erste mal gehört habe.

Answer (score 3):

Ich habe es jedenfalls schon häufig außerhalb der rechtsextremen Szene gehört. Vielleicht kannten die Nutzer die von Dir genannte Herkunft nicht, oder sie stimmt nicht.

In jedem Falle ist es kein besonders nettes Wort.

Comment: man hört es auch in "konservativen" Kreisen, die auch auch eher dem rechten Spektrum zuzuordnen sind

Comment: Mir ist das Wort zum ersten Mal in den Diskussionsforen von Spiegel Online aufgefallen. Dort fiel es eigentlich in jedem beliebigen Kontext und wurde dazu benutzt, um liberale bis linke Einstellungen zu diskreditieren. 

Es würde mich nicht wundern, wenn dieser Begriff im rechtsradikalen Umfeld sehr verbreitet ist. Inhaltlich würde das durchaus zum beobachteten Tenor passen ("Kriminelle Jugendliche ins Bootcamp" und "Todesstrafe für Kinderschänder" sind meiner persönlichen Einschätzung nach schon etwas mehr als "konservativ"). 

IMHO ein totales Unwort. :(

Comment: @ladybug es wäre 2011 auch beinahe Unwort des Jahres geworden. Zitat Wikipedia: Im Januar 2012 erhielt das Wort von der Gesellschaft für Deutsche Sprache als Unwort des Jahres 2011 den 2. Platz. In der Begründung gab die GfdS an, mit dem Wort werde „insbesondere in Internet-Foren das ethische Ideal des ‚guten Menschen‘ in hämischer Weise aufgegriffen, um Andersdenkende pauschal und ohne Ansehung ihrer Argumente zu diffamieren und als naiv abzuqualifizieren“ und kritisierte die aus ihrer Sicht 2011 einflussreich gewordene Funktion des Wortes als „Kampfbegriff gegen Andersdenkende“.

Comment: @cgnieder Für [2015](http://www.unwortdesjahres.net/index.php?id=44) hat es mit der Wahl dann doch geklappt. (Die Jury ist allerdings unabhängig von der GfdS.)